# How to check if id already exists in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, mysqli

I would like to check if **mycode_sn** exists in database before anything.
If **mycode_sn** doesn't exist, do nothing.

This is function:

```
function input_me_by_mycode($input_type, $input_id, $total_number)
    {
        if ($input_type == 'mycode') {
            $my_info = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array(
                'mycode_sn' => $input_id
            ))->row();

            }

                echo '<tr id="entry_row_' . $total_number . '">;

    }
```

I have tried in several ways, but obviously I do not know that well.

Now in the case that doesn't exist I get message:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function input_me_by_mycode($input_type, $input_id, $total_number)
{
    if ($input_type == 'mycode') {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycode_sn = '$input_id' ");
        $result = $query->result_array();

        if (!empty($result)) {
            echo "ID Exist. ID is : ".$result[0]['mycode_sn'];
        } else {
            echo "ID doesn't Exist.";
        }

    } 
    else {
        echo "Input Type is not equesl to 'mycode' ";
    }   
}
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense In controller this will be get with  `$this->input->post('input_id');`. So no prob

Comment: What you just said is irrelevant to sql injection and doesn't protect anything.

Comment: @YourCommonSense https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input

Comment: It's a pity that you don't understand that all your links are irrelevant. So I'll just leave it as a warinig for more cautous users.

Comment: @YourCommonSense click this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#security-filtering and check 3rd bullet point ***Filters the GET/POST/COOKIE array keys, permitting only alpha-numeric (and a few other) characters.***

Comment: @YourCommonSense My little project is completely closed and is only available on a local network. Safety did not really matter this time. In any case, thank you both for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

use active record  `num_rows()` for checking records

```
public function input_me_by_mycode($input_type, $input_id, $total_number)
{
    if ($input_type == 'mycode') {
         $this->db->where('mycode_sn',$input_id);
         $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
         $result = $query->row();

       if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            echo "ID Exist. ID is : ".$result->mycode_sn;
        } else {
            echo "ID doesn't Exist.";
        }

    } 
    else {
        echo "Input Type is not equesl to 'mycode' ";
    }   
}
```